# how to exclude certain path in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

For example in v5 I could do this:

```
<Route
  path={/^(?!.*ava\/search).*$/}
  element={<AvaHeader />}
/>
```

but it doesn't work in v6

Comment: `react-router-dom@6` routes don't use regular expressions, and always exactly match, so I suppose you could just *not* render a route for paths you don't want to match and render content on. If it's not as trivial as this can you clarify what exactly the behavior you are wanting?

Comment: yes, I understand that react-router-dom@v6 doesn't support regular expressions. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I can understand of your question you want to conditionally render this `AvaHeader` component when the route path ***doesn't*** contain any path with a `"*ava/search"` segment pair. I'd suggest creating a wrapper component to read the entire path and apply the regex.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const pathRegex = /^(?!.*ava\/search).*$/;

const AvaHeaderWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const isValid = pathRegex.test(pathname);
  
  return isValid ? children : null;
};
```

Render `AvaHeader` (*via wrapper component*) on its own route with `path="*"` within its own `Routes` component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="*"
    element={
      <AvaHeaderWrapper>
        <AvaHeader />
      </AvaHeaderWrapper>
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

Demo

[image: Edit how-to-exclude-certain-path-in-react-router-dom-v6]

Comment: thanks for your answer.
this solution definitely solves my problem.